# How to build basics to compete in slalom skating?

Tags: technique, skating

I have background in ice-skating and speed-skating, yet I find my technique a lot to be improved. Slalom skating is very different and demanding so much more from legs. So how to build basics to compete in slalom skating?

Answer (score 2):

**Basics moves**

I. Forwards Parallel (Fish): legs side-by-side and adjust turning by knees -- the

[image]

II. Forwards Monoline (Snake): both legs in the same line

[image]

3. Forwards Criss-Cross: other leg curls smoothly behind the other leg

[image]

4. Alternating Forwards Cross
5. Double Cross
6. Forwards One Foot

An incomplete slalom moves list can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freestyle_slalom_skating#List_of_slalom_moves).

**Breaking for Safety and Deep lunges to survive falls**

Drag and powerslide breaking is extremely useful for getting full-stop fast

[image]

where it is a combination of drag (T-stop) and ice hockey stop. Deep lunge can save you from many potential falls

[image]

[image]

that can be practised with Russian knees, should be familiar from ice-hockey for speed.

**Competitions by [WSSA rulebook](http://www.wssaskating.com/Download.aspx?did=1582)**

1. Freestlye skating
2. Classic freestyle slalom
3. Pair classic freestlye
4. Speed slalom
5. Battle freestyle slalom
6. Battle freestyle slides

**More**

1. The Art of Falling: Freestyle Slalom Skating book

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to set up "rockering". It's when outside wheels are less then inside. This will increase your maneuverability.

Like (76mm 80mm 80mm 76mm).

You will need time to get used to. Improve your balance.

Only then practice with basic elements such as "monoline", "criss-cross", "one foot".